# Locally convex topological vector space using semi norms

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Given a vector space and a family of semi-norms defined on it, I have to prove that it becomes a locally convex topological vector space.

To prove that it becomes a locally convex space I have to show that every open set containing zero contains a convex balanced absorbing open set.

But I can show only that such a convex balanced absorbing neighbourhood exist. How to show that such an open set exist ?

Comment: 1. You only have to show that it contains an open and convex set. That you can take them to be balanced and absorbing is something that you can the derive. 2. Even if you want to prove all three properties, you can simply ask yourself how one derives the topology from the family of seminorms and use that.

Answer (score 2):

If you start with a family $\{ |\cdot|_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$ of seminorms, then you can define the topology on the vector space $V$ as the weakest topology for which each seminorm $|\cdot|_{\alpha}$ is continuous. Equivalently, $B$ is a neighborhood of $0$ iff there exists a finite subset $\{ \alpha_{1},\cdots,\alpha_{n}\} \subseteq \Lambda$ and positive radii $\{ r_{1},\cdots,r_{n}\}$ such that
$$
            \bigcap_{j=1}^{n}\{ x : |x|_{\alpha_{j}} < r_{j} \} \subseteq B.
$$
This is a locally convex topology on $V$ with a base of neighborhoods defined as such intersections. Every set $\{ x : |x|_{\alpha} < r \}$ is balanced, convex and absorbing, and is open in this topology. And every open neighborhood $B$ of $0$ contains such a finite intersection, by the definition of the topology.